# unable to submit form loaded on the bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have dynamically created rows, on each rows i have a add button when user click on the add button then dynamically created form will be loaded on the bootstrap propover.
 [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aSZ6q/)

**my problem is :**

why this below jquery code is NOT getting call, If i  submit this form From bootstrap popover ?? I want to submit the form

```
 ...............
 ...............
console.log($("#"+formidd));// NOTE: i have accurate form id
         $("#"+formidd).validate({
            rules: {
                sproject_name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    required: true
                }, tooltip_options: {
                    sproject_name: {placement: 'center', html: true, trigger: 'focus'}
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) { 
                alert("form submit");
            }
        });
     ...............
     ...............
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.Please help me...

---

**Form looks like this:**(I want to validate It & submit it when user click ENTER)
[image]

---

**My html data look like this:**

```
<div id="project-div-id"> 
        <ul style="padding: 0px 0 2px;margin-left: 0px;">
         <li><span class="slilink"> tour </span>
            <img class="del_btn" src="/images/icons/add.gif"> 
              <form action="http://localhost/task/index.php/mypage" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="160subproj" id="160subproj"  style="display:none;">
                  <input type="text" value="1st">
                   <input class="red-tooltip" data-trigger="focus" placeholder="add sub project" name="project_name" type="text" >   
              </form>
         </li>

         <li><span class="slilink"> personal</span>
            <img class="del_btn" src="/images/icons/add.gif"> 
              <form action="http://localhost/task/index.php/mypage" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="161subproj" id="161subproj"  style="display:none;">
                  <input type="text" value="2st">
                   <input class="red-tooltip" data-trigger="focus" placeholder="add sub project" name="project_name" type="text" >   
              </form>
         </li>

    <li><span class="slilink"> business</span>
            <img class="del_btn" src="/images/icons/add.gif"> 
              <form action="http://localhost/task/index.php/mypage" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="162subproj" id="162subproj"  style="display:none;">
                  <input type="text" value="3rd form">
                   <input class="red-tooltip" data-trigger="focus" placeholder="add sub project" name="project_name" type="text" >   
              </form>
         </li>
     </div>
```

---

**This is my FULL jquery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { var formidd='';

        $('.add_btn').popover({
            html: true,
             title: function () {
                 formidd=$(this).parent().find('.projform_id').html();
                return $(this).parent().find('.sub_proj_head').html(); 
            }, 
            content: function() { 
                return $(this).parent().find('.sub_proj_content').html();
            }

        });

        $('.add_btn').click(function(e) { 

             console.log($("#"+formidd));//i have loaded form id
         $("#"+formidd).validate({
            rules: {
                sproject_name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    required: true
                }, tooltip_options: {
                    sproject_name: {placement: 'center', html: true, trigger: 'focus'}
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) { 
                alert("form submit");
            }
        });



            $('.add_btn').not(this).popover('hide');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function(e) {
            if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
                $('.add_btn').popover('hide');
            }  
        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME, SINCE TODAY AFTROON I WAS TRYING TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE.  STILL TRYING BUT looks like this is out of my capacity. PLEASE HELP....if you are unable to understand my question then please write comment..I will try to explain you in some better way...

Comment: Your question is very broad. What's the specific problem? Submitting and validating a form is an entire topic in itself. The fact that it's in a modal is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @isherwood I have update my question. Hope now its clear.

Comment: It appears it's because you're creating the popover content when it is initialized, using `$.html()`, but trying to attach the `$.valdate()` when the form doesn't yet exist. You need to run the `$.validate()` when the form is submitted, probably by observing the `submit` event from a parent element for the `content` that exists during `$.ready()`, or attach the `$.validate()` when the content is created (which is probably easier).

Comment: Move the `$.validate()` inside `content: function(){...}`. Understand the problem, though, that you're attaching `$.validate()` but it's not being attached to the one in your modal.

Comment: @JaredFarrish i moved to content..But still the same problem. http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140413-sbef-107kb.jpg

Comment: Create a http://jsfiddle.net with the associated libraries, so that the modal works with your current code.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I created fiddle as you said, please try to suggest me something else to solve this issue. i don see anybody accurately  helping me here except you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good practice, but you can try this out:

```
  var wait = setInterval( function() {
    if( $("#"+formidd).size() ) {
        clearInterval(wait);
         $("#"+formidd).validate({
            rules: {
                sproject_name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    required: true
                }, tooltip_options: {
                    sproject_name: {placement: 'center', html: true, trigger: 'focus'}
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) { 
                alert("form submit");
            }
        });
    }
  }, 100);
```

Comment: NOT WORKING... I TRIED YOURS CODE..